# Ошибка SQL Error Number: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Использую CI.
Пытаюсь записать serialize() строку, но получаю ошибку

> Error Number: 1064
>
> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'WHERE id = '1'' at line 4
>
> UPDATE pages SET content =
>   'a:7:{s:5:\"dutch\";s:0:\"\";s:7:\"english\";s:17:\"regerg erg
>   ergerg\";s:10:\"indonesian\";s:0:\"\";s:7:\"russian\";s:32:\"русиянский
>   язык
>   х\";s:18:\"simplified-chinese\";s:0:\"\";s:7:\"spanish\";s:0:\"\";s:7:\"turkish\";s:0:\"\";}',
>   WHERE id = '1'
>
> Filename: models/Pages_model.php
>
> Line Number: 101

Строка для записи:

```
a:7:{s:5:"dutch";s:0:"";s:7:"english";s:17:"regerg erg ergerg";s:10:"indonesian";s:0:"";s:7:"russian";s:29:"русиянский язык";s:18:"simplified-chinese";s:0:"";s:7:"spanish";s:0:"";s:7:"turkish";s:0:"";}
```

Код model:

```
function edit_page($data = array())
    {
        if ($data)
        {
            $sql = "
                UPDATE {$this->_db}
                SET
                    content = " . ((is_array($data['content'])) ? $this->db->escape(serialize($data['content'])) : $this->db->escape($data['content'])) . ",
                WHERE id = " . $this->db->escape($data['id']) . "
            ";

            $this->db->query($sql);

            if ($this->db->affected_rows())
            {
                return TRUE;
            }
        }

        return FALSE;
    }
```

Благодарен за любую помощь!

Comment: Запятая перед WHERE не должна же стоять?

Comment: Да, проблема в этом. Оформите ответ)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Уберите запятую перед WHERE

```
$sql = "
            UPDATE {$this->_db}
            SET
                content = " . ((is_array($data['content'])) ? $this->db->escape(serialize($data['content'])) : $this->db->escape($data['content'])) . "
            WHERE id = " . $this->db->escape($data['id']) . "
        ";
```